# How do I get a Palette for my bitmap once Picasso Loads it?

Tags: android, picasso, android-palette

In October 2014, Jake Wharton wrote [Coercing Picasso to Play With Palette](http://jakewharton.com/coercing-picasso-to-play-with-palette/). In it, there are 2 methods being pondered:

1. **Using a Transformation** that generates the palette. The advantage of this is that the palette is generated on Picasso's worker thread and is *ready* when the image is loaded. The disadvantage, however, seems to be that I'm getting palettes that don't match the picture. At the moment I only run one of these transformations at a time.
2. **Using a `Callback`** that `onSuccess` gets the bitmap from the `ImageView` and generates the Palette. I can't help but focus on the `// Ew!` that Jake puts at the end of this line and I quite agree with it.

The post mentioned above was written in October 2014. Now that we're months past the discussion, I'm wondering what is the recommended method?
There was also a discussion about associating `meta data` with bitmaps. Is that implemented? How would I use it?

My `Transformation` code (not final, I've just started looking into this):

```
public final class PaletteGenerator
  implements Transformation {

    private final int numColors;
    @Getter private Palette palette;

    @Override public Bitmap transform (final Bitmap source) {
        palette = null;
        final Palette palette = numColors > 0
                                ? Palette.generate (source, numColors)
                                : Palette.generate (source);
        return source;
    }

    @Override public String key () {
        return String.format (Locale.ENGLISH, "%s:%d", getClass ().getCanonicalName (), numColors);
    }

    public PaletteGenerator () {
        this (0);
    }

    public PaletteGenerator (final int c) {
        numColors = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Jake Wharton *there is no good way yet*

What I ended up doing was that I went with the Transformation method, with the ugly code encapsulated & hidden in the attic.

```
public final class PaletteGeneratorTransformation
  implements Transformation {

    private static final Map<Bitmap, Palette> CACHE = new WeakHashMap<> ();
    private final int    numColors;

    @Override public Bitmap transform (final Bitmap source) {
        if (!CACHE.containsKey (source)) {
            final Palette palette = numColors > 0
                      ? Palette.generate (source, numColors)
                      : Palette.generate (source);
            CACHE.put (source, palette);
        }

        return source;
    }

    @Override public String key () {
        return getClass ().getCanonicalName () + ":" + numColors;
    }

    public PaletteGeneratorTransformation () {
        this (0);
    }

    public PaletteGeneratorTransformation (final int c) {
        numColors = c;
    }

    public static abstract class Callback
      implements com.squareup.picasso.Callback {
        private final ImageView target;

        public Callback (final ImageView t) {
            target = t;
        }

        @Override public void onSuccess () {
            onPalette (CACHE.get (((BitmapDrawable) target.getDrawable ()).getBitmap ()));
        }

        @Override public void onError () {
            onPalette (null);
        }

        public abstract void onPalette (final Palette palette);
    }
}
```

In my Activity, I do something along these lines:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load (getPhotoUri())
    .transform (new PaletteGeneratorTransformation (DEFAULT_NUM_COLORS))
    .into (photo, new PaletteGeneratorTransformation.Callback (photo) {
                        @Override public void onPalette (final Palette palette) {
                            themeWithPalette (palette);
                        }
                    });
```

The only problem remaining is that I know there's ugliness hidden in the attic and for now that has to remain my dirty little secret.

Answer (score -1):

```
Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            viewHolder.mItemImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Drawable image = viewHolder.mItemImage.getDrawable();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }
    };
    Picasso.with(viewHolder.mItemImage.getContext()).load("url").into(viewHolder.mItemImage);
```

Comment: There's no mention of a Palette or Palette generation here. I don't think you read the question.

Comment: Also this approach will, at best, start the Palette generation **after** the bitmap is loaded. I'll have to throw it back on a background thread and post the resulting Palette (if any) to the UI thread to apply the Palette to the activity.

Comment: I dont get why the downvote, you get the bitmap and then you can call Pallete generation from there...

Comment: I simply suggested a different way to get bitmap

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.