# Android: Get the darker color code of Picasso Image

Tags: android, picasso, palette, android-palette

I am developing an application, which is mainly image based application.
In my application I am taking the images from server and showing in Rounded image view which is customize. To download and show images i am using **Picasso**.

Now the need of application is:

I want to get the primary or darker color code (In Hex format) of images in variables, which are in custom image view and applied using **Picasso**.

I had gone through the blog Written By [JAKE WHARTON](http://jakewharton.com/coercing-picasso-to-play-with-palette/) and from [Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705100/how-do-i-get-a-palette-for-my-bitmap-once-picasso-loads-it)
 But i am not able to get the hex code.

Please suggest me what should i do with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You added palette tag to the question, which is what i would recommend. Have you used it? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

Comment: Yes i tried https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

Comment: Then I suggest you to post that code ;) 
It will make it much more possible for the community to compare your code with their own, possibly working code of feeding a Picasso-retreived image into palette.

Comment: When reading your question again it's not clear where the problems is, do you get a color from palette, but the question is really how to make it from int to hex?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android